Unique solution to ODE
There is a basic ODE - Differential Equation.
y' = 2x , solution is f(x) = x²
Code:
  def deriv (y,x) :
    return 2 * x

#  time points
x = np.linspace ( 0 , 10)

# initial condition
y0 = 1

# solve ODE
solution = odeint ( deriv , y0 , x )
y = solution [ : , 0 ]

# plot results
plt.plot ( x , y )
plt.title("Equa diff y' = 2x  " )
plt.ylabel("value")
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.show()

# Find exact value at time 10 :  It's not ok
print(" At time 10 , my value will be " ,np.interp(10, x, y))

# 101.000000001241

Result:

I only need the numeric solution for x = 10, my interpolation solution is wrong and should be 100, not 101.00000001241.
I have tried to limit linspace to (3,3) or (10,10) with no luck.

Please give some more results of your research. Of course numerical integration and interpolation contribute both errors relative to the exact solution. What is the error level to be expected, for instance using the basic facts and ideas from the documentation? Does the found error markedly exceed these first estimates?

Just... don't plot (remove all the matplot code) and don't generate more data than you need? (e.g. linespace up to 3 instead of 20?)

I'm not sure what's your question. Are you looking for the fastest ODE-solving Python library, or are you concerned that numpy gave you different results than sympy?

Hello, I have edited my question with a simplier style.

You need to fresh up your math, the exact solution is y(x) = y0 + x^2, so that y(10) = 1 + 100 = 101. Now one could still ask why the numerical solution for this simple quadrature problem is not more accurate, but odeint uses multi-step methods which have a different behavior than one-step or RK methods.

The error in this case is 1.241e-8, which is pretty good.  You seem to have forgotten that the initial condition y(0) = 1.  odeint() did a fine job here.

I looked up the interp function and if I'm understanding it correctly, the function approxumates the wanted value via linear interpolation. That means the function only "draws a line" going in the same direction as the function we want to approximate, and points at the place where the function value would be if it was of the same shape as the line. This means it's impossible to get a perfectly accurate solution using this function.
As you already noticed, sympy gave you a more accurate result than numpy. That's because numpy uses numerical approximations while sympy uses syymbolic computation. Approximations are being used in cases where you don't need perfectly accurate answer, but you need it quickly computed.
Is this the answer you were looking for? Or do you need something else?
